# Can't mail ams to rogers with cronjob

Tags: php, cron, sms

I have a cronjob that sends sms to my users (in canada) and it used to work until now.

my cronjob:
/usr/bin/php -q /home/hthert/public_html/mail.php

sending sms

```
mail("4034714777@txt.bell.ca", null, $email_body, $extra ); // Bell
mail("4034714777@sms.fido.ca", null, $email_body, $extra ); // Fido
mail("4034714777@msg.telus.com", null, $email_body, $extra ); // Koodo
mail("4034714777@vmobile.ca", null, $email_body, $extra ); // Virgin
mail("4034714777@txt.windmobile.ca", null, $email_body, $extra ); // Wind
```

now ROGERS suddenly doesn't get the sms anymore.
And the funny thing is that they ONLY don't get the sms if it's sent with the cronjob. If i go to my mail.php file through my browsers, all sms go through. So i guess rogers somehow blocks my mail IF i isa a conjoin (only if i use a crounjog)
Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: There shouldn't be any noticeable difference between you running the PHP code by hand, and the cronjob. Try using your own email address as to the To field, and try it both from the command line and from the cronjob; you'll be able to compare the contents of the two emails to see what differences there are.

Comment: yes, i did that, and that really confuses me, because when i use my email address it works (even with cronjob) but with the rogers phone number it doesn't work. however, the rogers phone number does work when i DONT use the cronojob... VERY strange

Comment: Sorry, I think you misunderstood me. Get the two emails that were sent, and actually compare the contents of the two of them - see if there are differences in the headers, if the body is formatted differently, and so on.

Comment: Also - is there a valid From address on the emails your sending out? Do you get bounces if things fail, or do things just silently fail? You might need to ask Rogers if there's some debugging they can do - I guess it's also possible that if you're using the cronjob to send a few messages in one go, then it's being picked up as spam somewhere along the way, and getting discarded.